# What's a good strategy to prepare my hosting for a huge spike in traffic?

Tags: web-hosting, server, traffic

A regular small website doesn't need dedicated high powered servers on a daily basis for hosting. But cheap $10-$20 a month hosting will probably cripple fairly quickly under a traffic spike.

What is a good financially responsible strategy to be able to prepare to handle a huge (and potentially temporary) spike in traffic without crippling a website?

Comment: You will have to ask your host. I was a web host and I would have distributed your site over several shared host servers or a few dedicated servers prior to the increase. From there, a variety of load balancing techniques can be employed. I would use a router for the load balancing. I could have done this quickly and simply with enough warning. Most hosts can do exactly the same thing assuming that they have the imagination to. I would not have charged anything for this. A bit of good will goes a long way. Cheers!!